# How to install Google Fit app in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, installation

I am using Android emulator with Google API 29 and Play Store. I have to install Google Fit since my application uses its API.

However trying to install it in Play Store brings up  `Your device is not compatible with this version`.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the present time there is no way to install Google Fit for Android on an emulator. Interestingly, you can have your app interact with the Google Fit for Android API even without Fit installed and it will prompt you to allow Fit to share data with your app. You just can't install Fit to actually enter manual data.

Comment: oh damn!! in iOS we can interact with the Apple health app in the simulator itself. Thought it is the same for android. so https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started   is this the correct way?? and if I want to add say a step count and read that step count I need to access the googleFit API. there is no way I can manually enter it using the app?

Comment: As far as I found there is no way to enter manual data other than the Fit app.

Comment: I was able to install Google Fit in Android Studio emulator, so this answer is at the present time not true.